# Outlook Change Password Prompt - What enables this, and what do I put for Exchange Server?

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook, outlook-2010, password-management, cas

One of my end users sent me this screen, which is obviously indicative of an expired user password

[image]

- I'm unable to replicate this in my lab, nor do I know what value to put in for Exchange.  (is it just the CAS server?)
- What are the required version of Exchange and Outlook to enable this?

I'm posting here because searching for anything relating to Outlook and password prompts brings up a whole different set of issues that dominates the web.

Comment: I haven't seen that but maybe once or twice ever.  I'm pretty sure though that it is displayed when the user's password has expired and they are using Outlook over RPC/HTTPS (Outlook Anywhere).  IIRC though, it still wouldn't let you change it.  I think you can actually find the Change Windows Password form in the Custom Forms library within Outlook.  I don't have an on-prem Exchange or client older than 2013 to check with nowadays though.

Comment: @TheCleaner I don't see any forms in the OrgForms library...

Comment: Is this user setup for outlook over rpc/https?  Sorry, I don't have a great way to research this anymore.  I also don't think it works, meaning you asked how to enable it, but I think it is carry over from old Outlook clients.  Was she upgraded from an old version of Outlook on her computer?  Check the forms libraries on her computer.

Comment: Yes all clients are RPC/HTTPS ... I don't have any of the other information